# Find out what has been installed on harddrive

Tags: hard-drive, windows-registry

I have a computer where I need to find out if a specific set of software have been installed on it before.

But the very first problem is the user of the computer has changed in a new hard drive. And the old one is gone.

Is it still possible to find out what software have been installed previously?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If that drive was the only hard drive, and a full new install was performed on the replacement then no. If full-backups were made and kept, those would reveal what software had been previously installed.

If the user's data files had already been restored, you might infer what software *might* have previously produced those files and therefore which software might have been present.

If the computer had two drives, C and D, with some software installed on D, then D was replaced without un-installing software, then if the operating system was Windows, the registry on C would reveal what software had been installed on D.

Summary: You should give more details!

Comment: I'm simply the very first case. Thanks for the info